# When Install spacy it show failed to install builed dependencies

Tags: spacy

When i try to install spacy it show error failed to  install build dependencies.I have tried on all things but cannot solve it .
I donwload from following website but no help https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ 
Please help me.i am in huge trouble

Comment: It shows error  command 'cl.exe' failed.No such file or directory.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to install spaCy is to just run `pip install -U spacy`, or, if you're using `conda`, run `conda install -c conda-forge spacy`. Alternatively, you can compile it from source by cloning the [repo](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy), but usually that isn't necessary. More info can be found [here](https://spacy.io/usage#installation).

Comment: When i run this command it show error found :"Cl.exe no such file or directory.While i already have visual build tools installed

Comment: I am using window 7 32 bit with python 3.7.

Comment: [spaCy no longer supports 32-bit Python](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/README.md#install-spacy)